# Time for import from XML to MySQL

Tags: mysql, xml, import, execution-time

I use a script to import an XML file into an MySQL database. The XML contains around 165.000 datasets.

At the moment I have imported 25.000 datasets - and this has takes now around 70 mins. Is that normal?

The import runs from shell on an dedicated server with following specs:

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1620 v2 @ 3.70GHz
8 Cores, 10240KB Cache
RAM 64GB

load average: 3.53, 3.06, 2.80

I can't believe that should be normal?

EDIT (add more info)

MySQL v 5.5.50

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<amateures>
  <amateur>
    <id></id>
    <login></login>
    <figur></figur>
    <vote_rating></vote_rating>
    <haarfarbe></haarfarbe>
    <gewicht></gewicht>
    <groesse></groesse>
    <plz></plz>
    <sternzeichen></sternzeichen>
    <vorlieben></vorlieben>
    <vorlieben_en></vorlieben_en>
    <uebermich></uebermich>
    <uebermich_en></uebermich_en>
    <geschlecht></geschlecht>
    <staat></staat>
    <gebtag></gebtag>
    <regdate></regdate>
    <urls>
      <profil></profil>
      <register></register>
    </urls>
    <images>
      <overview></overview>
      <overview_fsk16></overview_fsk16>
      <overview_big></overview_big>
      <overview_fsk16_big></overview_fsk16_big>
    </images>
    <videos>
      <video>
        <title></title>
        <title_en></title_en>
        <beschreibung></beschreibung>
        <beschreibung_en></beschreibung_en>
        <playtime></playtime>
        <id></id>
        <img_fsk16></img_fsk16>
        <img></img>
        <imgani></imgani>
        <videourl></videourl>
        <category></category>
        [...]
        <category></category>
      </video>
      <video>
        [...]
      </video>
    </videos>
  </amateur>
</amateures>
```

and php file:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -n
<?php
function OpenDB () {
  $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','','');
  if(!$connect) die ("Connection to SQL-Server failed!");
  $database = mysqli_select_db($connect, "");
  if(!$database) die ("Selection of Database failed!");
  return $connect;
}
$connect = OpenDB();

$count = 0;
$countnew = 0;
$countvid = 0;
$starttime = time();

$xml = simplexml_load_file("import.xml");

$query = "update amateur set deleted = 1";
mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$query = "delete from amateur_vid";
$res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

foreach ($xml->amateur as $amateur) {
  $count++;
  $amateur_id                 = $amateur->id;
  $amateur_login              = utf8_decode($amateur->login);
  $amateur_figur              = $amateur->figur;
  $amateur_vote_rating        = $amateur->vote_rating;
  $amateur_haarfarbe          = $amateur->haarfarbe;
  $amateur_gewicht            = $amateur->gewicht;
  $amateur_groesse            = $amateur->groesse;
  $amateur_plz                = $amateur->plz;
  $amateur_sternzeichen       = $amateur->sternzeichen;
  $amateur_vorlieben          = $amateur->vorlieben;
  $amateur_vorlieben_en       = $amateur->vorlieben_en;
  $amateur_uebermich          = $amateur->uebermich;
  $amateur_uebermich_en       = $amateur->uebermich_en;
  $amateur_geschlecht         = $amateur->geschlecht;
  $amateur_staat              = $amateur->staat;
  $amateur_gebtag             = $amateur->gebtag;
  $amateur_regdate            = $amateur->regdate;

  foreach ($amateur->urls as $url) {
    $amateur_profil             = $url->profil;
    $amateur_register           = $url->register;
  }

  foreach ($amateur->images as $image) {
    $amateur_overview           = $image->overview;
    $amateur_overview_fsk16     = $image->overview_fsk16;
    $amateur_overview_big       = $image->overview_big;
    $amateur_overview_fsk16_big = $image->overview_fsk16_big;
  }

  $amateur_vorlieben          = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $amateur_vorlieben);
  $amateur_vorlieben_en       = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $amateur_vorlieben_en);
  $amateur_uebermich          = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $amateur_uebermich);
  $amateur_uebermich_en       = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $amateur_uebermich_en);

  $query = "select * from amateur where amateur_id = $amateur_id";
  $res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

  if(mysqli_num_rows($res) == 0) {
    $countnew++;
    $query = "insert into amateur (amateur_id, amateur_login, amateur_figur, amateur_vote_rating, amateur_haarfarbe, amateur_gewicht, amateur_groesse, amateur_plz, amateur_sternzeichen, amateur_vorlieben, amateur_vorlieben_en, amateur_uebermich, amateur_uebermich_en, amateur_geschlecht, amateur_staat, amateur_gebtag, amateur_regdate, amateur_profil, amateur_register, amateur_overview, amateur_overview_fsk16, amateur_overview_big, amateur_overview_fsk16_big) values ($amateur_id, '$amateur_login', '$amateur_figur', '$amateur_vote_rating', '$amateur_haarfarbe', '$amateur_gewicht', '$amateur_groesse', '$amateur_plz', '$amateur_sternzeichen', '$amateur_vorlieben', '$amateur_vorlieben_en', '$amateur_uebermich', '$amateur_uebermich_en', '$amateur_geschlecht', '$amateur_staat', '$amateur_gebtag', '$amateur_regdate', '$amateur_profil', '$amateur_register', '$amateur_overview', '$amateur_overview_fsk16', '$amateur_overview_big', '$amateur_overview_fsk16_big')";
    $res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
  } else {
    $query = "update amateur set amateur_login='$amateur_login', amateur_figur='$amateur_figur', amateur_vote_rating='$amateur_vote_rating', amateur_haarfarbe='$amateur_haarfarbe', amateur_gewicht='$amateur_gewicht', amateur_groesse='$amateur_groesse', amateur_plz='$amateur_plz', amateur_sternzeichen='$amateur_sternzeichen', amateur_vorlieben='$amateur_vorlieben', amateur_vorlieben_en='$amateur_vorlieben_en', amateur_uebermich='$amateur_uebermich', amateur_uebermich_en='$amateur_uebermich_en', amateur_geschlecht='$amateur_geschlecht', amateur_staat='$amateur_staat', amateur_gebtag='$amateur_gebtag', amateur_regdate='$amateur_regdate', amateur_profil='$amateur_profil', amateur_register='$amateur_register', amateur_overview='$amateur_overview', amateur_overview_fsk16='$amateur_overview_fsk16', amateur_overview_big='$amateur_overview_big', amateur_overview_fsk16_big='$amateur_overview_fsk16_big', deleted=0 where amateur_id = $amateur_id";
    $res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    if(!$res)
      die($query);
  }

  foreach ($amateur->videos as $videos) {
    foreach ($videos->video as $video) {
      $vids_title         = $video->title;
      $vids_title_en      = $video->title_en;
      $vids_beschreibung  = $video->beschreibung;
      $vids_beschreibung_en = $video->beschreibung_en;
      $vids_playtime        = $video->playtime;
      $vids_id              = $video->id;
      $vids_img_fsk16       = $video->img_fsk16;
      $vids_img             = $video->img;
      $vids_imgani          = $video->imgani;
      $vids_videourl        = $video->videourl;
      $vids_category        = $video->category;

      $query = "insert into amateur_vid (amateur_id, vids_title, vids_title_en, vids_beschreibung, vids_beschreibung_en, vids_playtime, vids_id, vids_img_fsk16, vids_img, vids_imgani, vids_videourl, vids_category) values ($amateur_id, '$vids_title', '$vids_title_en', '$vids_beschreibung', '$vids_beschreibung_en', '$vids_playtime', '$vids_id', '$vids_img_fsk16', '$vids_img', '$vids_imgani', '$vids_videourl', '$vids_category')";
      $res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
      $setid = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
      $countvid++;
    }
  }

}

$endtime = time();
$interval = $endtime-$starttime;

$query = "select count(id) from amateur where deleted = 1";
$res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$countdel = mysqli_result($res,0,0);

$query = "delete from amateur where deleted = 1";
mysqli_query($connect, $query);

?>
```

My PHP script has a small issue. I cannot import all categories - it will be only import one category each video.

I start already a question for that.

Hope this informations enough? This script was writter by an programmer for me many years before for another XML import. I adopt and change it for this new XML file.

I'm not a professional programmer and not an native English speaker - so please talk with "easy" words to me ;)

Comment: You need to provide more information : what versions of MySQL are you using, what kind of datasets are you inserting, etc. ?

Comment: more infos added ...

Comment: I don't think it should take that long. You'll need to work out what the computer is doing (is it doing anything else), and which part of your code takes the time. If you have 1 dataset, how long does it take? It's probably best to get a programmer in again.

Comment: The script is still importing - now since around 5,5 hours ... Yeah, if I could found a programmer, I would do that ... My skills are limited, not enough to try to do it myself. All the tutorials I found are simple imports and this XML file from the affiliate system is a bit more complex ...